# How to return to previous point after `org-clock-goto`?

Tags: org-mode, point

In org-mode, `C-c C-x C-j` executes `org-clock-goto`, jumping the cursor to the currently active or most recently used clock.

After using this, I almost always want to go back to the point where I was, often another buffer.  I would expect running `org-clock-goto` a second time would get me there, toggling back to where I started. But unfortunately, that doesn't work. `org-clock-goto` does only what the name says.

In search of a solution, I came up with a pair of simple elisp functions:

```
(defun my/org-clock-goto ()
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-set "before goto clock")
  (org-clock-goto))

(defun my/org-clock-return ()
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-jump "before goto clock"))
```

This only works if I am starting off in a buffer which is a file (not `*scratch*` for instance). But more importantly, what I really want is a *single* function bound to `C-c C-x C-j` that will let me jump between the original point and the last clock.

Any hints?

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you want:

    `(defadvice org-clock-goto (around bp/org-clock-goto--around) "Push mark to global-mark-ring for navigation purposes." (if (eq last-command 'org-clock-goto) (pop-global-mark) (push-mark (point)) ad-do-it)) (ad-activate 'org-clock-goto)`

Pushes a mark to the `gobal-mark-ring` when using `org-clock-goto`. Using `org-clock-goto` immediately afterwards will jump back to the starting position. When not just jumping back and forth, use `pop-global-mark` (C-x C-SPC) to go back.

Comment: Getting warmer... *If* the point is not already at the most recent clock, then `org-clock-goto` should `(push-mark (point))` first before going there. But *otherwise* (which is to say, if the mark is already at the active or most recent clock) then `org-clock-goto` should `(pop-global-mark)`. If you can incorporate those conditions into this defadvice, then I expect it will work very nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This advised `org-clock-goto` will `push-mark` to the `global-mark-ring` whenever you are not at the currently clocked item. Otherwise it will jump back to the starting position with `pop-global-mark`. (NOTE: `org-clock-goto` will no longer work correctly without an open clock.)

```
(defadvice org-clock-goto (around org-clock-goto--around)
  "If not at clocked item already, push mark to `global-mark-ring'."
  (if (and (org-clocking-p)
           (< (save-excursion (outline-back-to-heading) (point))
              org-clock-marker)
           (> (save-excursion (outline-next-heading) (point))
              org-clock-marker))
      (pop-global-mark)
    (push-mark (point)) ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'org-clock-goto)
```

Comment: I accepted this because it works nicely *if* there is an active clock running. But with no active clock running, `org-clock-goto` is completely broken by this. I spent quite a bit of time trying to hack it into shape, but had no luck :(

Comment: What do you mean by "completely broken"? Besides pushing a mark it's default behavior (jumps to the most recently clocked item) for me.

Comment: If I play around with this, moving around to different places, clocking in and out and trying to toggle between the clock and a mark, it frequently just behaves as if the defadvice were not in effect. But sometimes (I can't tell you how to reproduce it reliably, but this is the really broken part) the point jumps unexpectedly to another mark in the ring, before the most recent one. If it matters I'm on Emacs 24.3.1 and Org-mode 8.2.10.

Comment: You probably push some more marks to the ring before using `org-clock-goto` again. In that case, using `(point-to-register 1)` and `(register-to-point 1)` instead of `push-mark` and `pop-global-mark` would be the way to go.

Comment: I should replace the line `pop-global-mark` with `(point-to-register 1)` and the following line,  `(push-mark (point)) ad-do-it))` with `(register-to-point 1) ad-do-it))`? I tried this just now ,but the point would not return to where I started from.